# qgis2web problem with lots of data

Tags: qgis, javascript, qgis2web

A few month ago I was able to make a polygon map of population: http://supermap.hostei.com

Today I opened the same QGIS project and tried qgis2web again. The plugin interface had responding problems. Then, I tried to make the same map as before. The HTML, JS, and CSS files were generated successfully, but my Chrome browser crashed when opening the files. Firefox was able to display the map, but the navigation such as zooming, panning, and popups were very slow.

My shapefile has 7000 rows/features. I tried it with 200 rows now and it seems to be working smoothly. I also tried another dataset of US county polygons and got the same problem: http://vehiclethefts.netne.net/map1/

Do you know why this might be or any solution so that I am still be able to generate maps with 1000+ features?

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution myself.

I realized the county polygons were very detailed with lots of vertexes.

So, I first simplified the polygons by removing most of the vertexes with Simplify Geometry and then produced the web files again with the simplified shapefile. The navigation was smooth this time.

The produced HTML, JS, and CSS files went from 160 MB to 3 MB.